# Why does the @family tag add dots between words in roxygen2?

Tags: r, roxygen2, r-package

I am writing an R package and create documentation using roxygen2. I build the package and the documentation using the button *Build & Reload* in RStudio. According to RStudio's output, it uses `devtools::document(roclets=c('rd', 'namespace'))` to compile the documentation.

I want to use the `@family` tag to link together a number of functions in the documentation and this is where my problem occurs. This line

```
#' @family functions returning some object
```

is converted in the .Rd file to the following

```
\seealso{
    Other functions.returning.some.object: \code{\link{test2}}
 }
```

I don't want the dots between the words. I have an older package, where this does not happen, even if I recompile the documentation in the exact same setting as I compile the new package. I can see no fundamental difference between this older package and my new attempt.

I have written a very simple test package, where the problem also occurs. It contains a single R file (`testpackage.R`):

```r
#' Test function 1
#' 
#' @param x a number
#' 
#' @family functions returning some object
#' @family aggregate functions
#' 
#' @export

test1 <- function(x) {
  x*x
} 


#' Test function 2
#' 
#' @param x a number
#' 
#' @family functions returning some object
#' @family aggregate functions
#'  
#' @export

test2 <- function(x) {
  x*x*x
}
```

The DESCRIPTION file is

```
Package: testpackage
Type: Package
Title: Package for testing purposes
Version: 1.0
Date: 2015-05-21
Author: Me
Maintainer: Me <me@somewhere.com>
Description: Package for testing purposes
License: GPL-3
```

NAMESPACE is generated by roxygen. For the documentation `test1.Rd`, I get:

```latex
% Generated by roxygen2 (4.1.1): do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/testpackage.R
\name{test1}
\alias{test1}
\title{Test function 1}
\usage{
test1(x)
}
\arguments{
\item{x}{a number}
}
\description{
Test function 1
}
\seealso{
Other aggregate.functions: \code{\link{test2}}

Other functions.returning.some.object: \code{\link{test2}}
}
```

with the unwanted dots in the `\seealso` section. Clearly, the number of words in the `@family` tag seems not to matter. I have tried enclosing the text in quotation marks, various kinds of brackets, etc. with no positive effect. Of course, I could edit the Rd files, but this would miss the point of using roxygen2.

`R CMD check` runs without warnings or errors on `testpackage`.

Why do these dots appear? And how can I get rid of them?

Comment: Actually, I find that @family produces no output in my .Rd files, using  Roxygen2-4.1.1 on R-3.2.3; possibly this is a feature only of as-yet-unreleased versions of Roxygen2.

Comment: But it does produce output for me, so it can't be that this feature is not yet supported. I think, you need to add the same `@family` tag to at least two functions, in order to have output.

Comment: Sorry, @Stibu, you're right on this.  I now get the family information but with those ugly dots, like you're getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `roxygen2` -- I've logged an issue [here](https://github.com/klutometis/roxygen/issues/477). It effectively results from the use of `unstack()`, which performs some unwanted conversions.

Comment: Thanks, I'm glad there is finally an explanation of this. Would you mind adding the explanations from the bug report here? I think it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded to Roxygen 5.0.0 (which is now the CRAN version) and found that the problem went away.

Comment: I have roxygen 5.0.1 now and unfortunately, the problem persists for me. Are you sure that the roxygen version is the only thing that changed?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I cannot say for sure whether other things changed. Four days isn't that long ago in some terms, but for an actively-developing project, it's quite a long time. And you and I may have quite different setups, too. All I can say is that I'm pretty sure updating roxygen fixed it.